# How can I make website exact fit to different screen resolutions?

Tags: jquery, html, web, adaptive-design

How do I adapt and **exact fit (i.e. height and width both)** to different resolutions? How to scale down image element as per screen resolutions maintaining their aspect ratio and positioning like left, top etc. Please help me out with- what approach should I take. Is making different images for different resolutions is only option?

Please check reference I want similar kind of result. Every element is adapting nicely on each n every resolution - [blacknegative.com](http://blacknegative.com)

Using HTML and Jquery!!!

Comment: why don't you just inspect the css and script used in your reference and work from those principles? Can inspect any element in browser console and get layout and css properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do this by getting screen resolution and all this are inherit in percentage wise
screen resolution, you can get this from any where, using javascript also or by applying 100% width

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) Framework like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: Thanks for response. But the problem I'm facing is with 100% height.It only adapt to width and take auto height to maintain aspect ratio. Please check reference I want similar kind of result. Every element is adapting nicely on each n every resolution http://www.blacknegative.com/

Comment: That would have been nice to know in your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Utilize CSS Frameworks like foundation and Bootstrap. Use CSS - Media Queries to make your website viewable in all sort of devices and in different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to set the size in the HTML/ASP variable as percent (e.g: 20%) instead of pixels
this will take the size of the window and modify all the elements as 100% represent full size.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Set all your dimensions to percentages.  You can also use css media queries to specifically target certain devices or resolutions.